# remove element of a string at a given index in excel vba

Tags: string, vba, excel, formatting

How do I remove an element of a string at a given index in excel vba? My current code looks like this:

```
Private Sub RemovePeriods_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim Cutoff As Integer

For i = 0 To 14283

Cutoff = InStr(1, Range("K6").Offset(i, 0).Value, ".", vbTextCompare)
If Cutoff > 0 Then

End If
Next i
End Sub
```

So in that last if statement I want to write code that removes the period at the index specified by cutoff. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you just want to remove all periods you can use `Replace()` - if you want to remove only specific periods then you can use Left() and Right() to get the portions of the string before and following the specific index, and concatenate them.

Comment: @TimWilliams you can use the `Start` and `Count` parameters of `Replace` to replace only some instances. (`Replace(string, ".", "", 1, 1, vbTextCompare)`  BTW you should post this as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do your requirments. Try this and let me know.

```
Private Sub RemovePeriods_Click()

        Dim i               As Integer
        Dim Cutoff          As Integer
        Dim rngData         As Range
        Dim strToReplace    As String

        'Assign String to replace here
        strToReplace = "."

        For i = 0 To 14283
            'Assign the cell to Range
            Set rngData = Range("K6").Offset(i, 0)
            Cutoff = InStr(1, rngData, strToReplace, vbTextCompare)
            If Cutoff > 0 Then
                'Apply Replace formula
                rngData = WorksheetFunction.Replace(rngData, Cutoff, Len(strToReplace), "")
            End If
        Next i

        Set rngData = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: also, for 14k cells, you might want to use a VBA array instead of the worsheet, unless you tell me it takes only less than a second on your computer, wich could be the case, but still i don't like it ^^